# Outer DIV doesn't expand with inner DIVs

Tags: css, html

I am wrapping my page inside a main  wrapper `div`  but outer `div` doesn't expand with inner div.

I want height of main outer div `main-wrapper` to grow with page contents which is not happening for some reason

I am trying to figure out this problem for sometime but so far no success.

I have set up [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nbaxZ/)

I would help in this regard.

HTML Structure sample

```
<!-- main Container -->
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header-wrapper"></div>
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Page-->
        <!-- banner image wrapper -->
        <div class="top-image-wrapper"></div>
        <!-- banner image wrapper -->
        <!-- page content wrapper -->
        <div id="page-content-area" class="page-content-area">
            <div id="pg-intro-area" class="pg-intro-area">
                <div class="page-title">
                     <h5>Page Title </h5>

                </div>
                <div class="page-text"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="pg-right-bar-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- page content wrapper -->
        <!-- Content Page-->
    </div>
    <div class="footer-wrapper"></div>
</div>
<!-- main Container -->
```

CSS Related

```
html, body,form { height:100%;   background-color:gray; }
body {
  font-family:  Verdana,"Trebuchet MS",Arial,sans-serif;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 16px;
  height:100%; margin:0;padding:0; border:0;
  color:#656565;
}
p
{
    text-align:justify;
    color:#687074;
}
hr 
{
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: medium none;
    height: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
h5 /* for page title*/
{
 font-size:15px;
 color:#028F41;   
 margin:5px 0;
}
.page-title-lbl
{
 font-size:15px;
 color:#028F41;   
 padding-left:105px;
 background-image:url("../images/title-bar.png");
 background-repeat:no-repeat; 
 text-shadow:0 0 0px #F6F6F6;
}
img
{
border:0px
}

a {
  color: #028F41;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

input {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height:20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color:#656565;
}
.btn 
{
    background-color: #0A8F36;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    height: 24px;
    line-height:24px;
}

.margin5-0
{
    margin:5px 0;
}
.margin10-0
{
    margin:10px 0;
}
.margin20-0
{
    margin:20px 0;
}
.padding5-0
{
   padding:10px 0;
}
.padding10-0
{
   padding:10px 0;
}
.padding20-0
{
   padding:20px 0;
}
.margin10-000
{
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
}
.margin00-5-0
{
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
}
.margin00-10-0
{
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
}
.margin20-000
{
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
}
.margin00-20-0
{
 margin:0 0 20px 0;
}

.main-wrapper
{
    width:1000px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
margin:0px auto 0px auto;
background-color:#fff;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
}
.header-wrapper
{
height:130px;
background-color:red;

}
.search-sm-wrapper
{
    float:right;
    width:250px;
    height:100px;   
}
.search-wrapper
{
    text-align:right;
    width:250px;
    height:25px;
}
.txtSearch 
{
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    border-right:0px;
}
.btn-search
{
float:right;
}

.language-wrapper
{
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    width:250px;
    height:20px;
}
.language-link 
{
    color:#656565;
}
.sm-wrapper
{
    float:right;
    width:250px;
    height:25px;
}
.menu-wrapper
{
    height:30px;
    width:1000px;
    background-color:yellow;
}

.content-wrapper
{
float:left;
height:auto;
}
.footer-wrapper
{
    float:left;
    width:1000px;
}
.brand-logos
{
    height:39px;
}
.marquee
{
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:39px;
    width:1000px;
    border:0px solid #f9f9f9;
}
.footer-banner
{
    float:left;
    height:96px;
    width:1000px;
}
.footer-menu
{
    display:none;
}
.footer-copyright
{
    float:left;
    height:20px;
    width:1000px;

}





.top-image-wrapper
{
    height:240px;
    margin-top:6px;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
}


/* home page*/
.hp-intro-area
{
    float:left;
    width:570px;
    margin-right:30px;
}
.hp-right-bar-wrapper
{
    float:left;   
    width:400px;
}
.tabs-wrapper
{
  margin:10px 0;
  background-color:#E5E5E5;
  height:210px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.tab-name-wrapper
{
  width:400px;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  background-color:#fff;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.tab-content-wrapper
{
 margin:0px 10px;
}
.hp-tab-image
{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    padding-right:10px;    
}

/* Page */
.page-content-area
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.page-sub-menu
{
    width:100%;
    height:23px;
    padding:0px 0px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.pg-intro-area
{
    float:left;
    width:570px;
    margin-right:30px;
}
.pg-right-bar-wrapper
{
    float:left;   
    width:400px;
}
```

Comment: The main wrapper is taking up the whole page?? http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/nbaxZ/1/

Comment: Try to remove the height:100%; styling on the main wrapper. Possibly also remove the same styling on the html/body/form.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
.main-wrapper{
    overflow:auto;
    /* other styles here */
}
```

Or sometimes it just helps to clear your floats properly:

```
.main-wrapper:before,
.main-wrapper:after {
    content : "";
    display : table;
}
.main-wrapper:after {
    clear : both;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what i was doing i used this & at that time it didnt work and now it works.. Thanks.. May be i did so many changes that i must have put it somewhere else. Anyways thanks .It solved my problem. Ignore my last first comment as i must have made some mistake first time when i added `overflow:auto;` at that time it added H-Scroll bar . Anyway thanks

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker you're welcome :) I know how you feel, after one makes 100s changes with no success, it's a bit frustrating and it's easy to *"get lost in code"* ;) Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

`display: block;`

and

`float: left;`

to your `.main-wrapper` class, so it will look like this:

```
.main-wrapper
{
        width:1000px;
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;

    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```